# Get Submitted Date of Assignment -Rest Api (Project Online)

Tags: project-server, project-online

I need to show history of last updated assignment of the resource. I am not sure which endpoint will give me the submitted date of the assignment.

[image]

Note: I need REST API endpoint for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i got the endpoint, below is the endpoint

```
/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/EnterpriseResources('<guid>')/Assignments('guid')/History
```